# Ruby on Rails Install Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rbenv

I am trying to get set up using rbenv and ruby on rails. Everything has been working fine (been working through Lynda.com Ruby on Rails Essential Training) until it came time to actually install the rails gem. It fails in the sam way every time. Can someone tell me what I need to do to continue with Rails?

I've used rbenv and have been set up with Ruby 2.1.1.

Provided Terminal Screenshot
[image]

Edit: I am calling sudo because when I try to install without sudo it provides the following (folder permissions provided for context)
[image]

Comment: you are not installing the gem properly. There is no need to use `sudo`. When you use `sudo`, you are using the system installed ruby, which like ruby2.0

Comment: @JustinWood I provided additional details to the post regarding sudo

Comment: You do not have `rbenv` loading your ruby properly. Please read the [documentation](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to learn how to load the ruby version for your [application](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-local) or [shell](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-shell).

Comment: I'll admit I am very new to command line interfaces and ruby development. I never set the local ruby version number. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never actually set the local ruby version with `rbenv local 2.1.1`. Everything worked like a charm after that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a working `rbenv` installation with 2.1.1 installed, you should just be able to remove `sudo` from the command:

```
gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Using `sudo` runs as root, which knows nothing of the local rbenv installation for your `mattcoker` user, so it uses the system's Ruby instead. Generally, when using rbenv locally on your machine, you should *never* need to use `sudo`.

Comment: I provided additional details to the post regarding sudo